# My website is not responsive on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, responsive

I'm building a Wordpress website at http://xscoder.com/wp-demo/test/

I am not able to make it responsive, although all CSS and JS scripts are successfully loaded, as you may see in the Inspector. I guess it's something related to slicknav, although I'm not sure about it, here's the code of my main.js file to call slicknav responsive JS:

```
$(function(){
        $('#menu-primary-menu').slicknav({
            prependTo: '.site-branding',
            label: '',
            allowParentLinks: true
        });
 });
```

May you guys can check my wesbite with the Chrome Inspector and see if there's something wronng, the Console soesn't print any error so I don't really know what I'm doing worng, I'm anewbie :)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question about HTML/CSS/JS, so you should ask them on [so].

Comment: did you add something like ` <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your head?

Comment: @rudyek that was the solution, thanks so much!

Comment: Great news!  I added it as an answer below.  Do you mind marking as the solution?  (check mark to the left of the answer)

Comment: i have quistion please help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349273/the-woocommerce-category-is-not-responsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times even if we have setup our media queries correctly, the site still isn't responsive to those queries.

You need to set a viewport in your header.php to fix this.  More often than not I find that this affects macs instead of PCs. but it's still a good idea to add this no matter the case.

In your site `<head>` add this code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And it should fix the problem.  This is telling the site to be aware of the device width that is viewing the site.

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your head tags:

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

I have not found a recent jQuery version in your head tags and SlickNav requires jQuery 1.7+.

I do not know if this is the solution for your issue, but try it.

Comment: But for compatibility with a number of things, one should use the old version of jQuery bundled with WordPress, as he's doing.

Comment: ... so there's a potential dilemma between compatibility with SlickNav and other things. Would depend on what else is use.

Comment: The solution was the missing 'viewport' meta tag, thank you so much anyway @Javi Torre